# apalike bibliography style refer to with numbers

Tags: bibtex

I am using the apalike bibliography style, since I want my references presented like [Fanty et al., 1993] to an article, and [Abut, 1990] to a book. It was working well in the beginning, but have suddently changed to numbers.
How to change it back to the original style of apalike?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You wrote "It was working well in the beginning, but have suddently changed to numbers." Do you recall what may have changed in your document when the citation style went from author-year to numeric? E.g., did you start loading a package that affects citations? I'm a dreadful psychic, and without specific information -- preferably in the form of an MWE that generates the problem behavior you want to fix -- as to what's going on, it's well-nigh impossible for me (and I suspect others as well) to offer helpful suggestions.